# Some contradictions in C(X)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

I'm reading Carothers' Real Analysis, 1ed. Here are two functions from C[0,1] used in his book,
[image]
[image]

See, both of them ∈ C[0,1] while function(b) is not bounded actually and function(c) does not converge in C[0,1].
Since [0,1] is a compact space in $\mathbb R$, so C[0,1] is a closed subspace of B([0,1])--the complete space of real valued bounded functions on [0,1].
Then contradiction produced:

1. function(b) is not bounded while it does being in C[0,1];
2. function(c) does not converges to a function in C[0,1], which shows that C[0,1] is not complete.
   I think there is something wrong with my understanding of C[0,1]. But I cannot figure it out?

P.S.
I think the second example is not appropriate cos it may not be Cauchy about which I'm not sure.

Comment: You don't state a definite question, so it is hard to determine what to answer.

Comment: @EricTowers: What I want to ask is how to remove two contradiction here. So second example is not Cauchy, which nevertheless is convergent and will not break down the property of completeness of C[0,1].

Answer (score 1):

Did someone tell you that $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$ contains all its limit points?  If so, then you have adequate ammunition to prove that assertion wrong.

The sequence of $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$ functions $g_n$ do not converge to a $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$ function.  $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$ functions are finite.  For any bound, $M$, you pick, there is an $N \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ such that for all $n>N$, $g_n\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right) > M$.  So the limit of the sequence of $g_n$ either is not a continuous function (perhaps it's a distribution, or lives in a less stringent space of functions), or does not exist (in this space of functions).

Comment: So both function sequence(b) and function sequence(c) are not Cauchy sequence, right?

Comment: @Frank_W:  That question requires a notion of norm of functions.  What method of measuring the distance between functions do you want to use?  Different norms will give different topologies will give different notions of open and closed.

Comment: In C[0,1], sup norm actually.

Comment: @Frank_W:  Well, clearly, the limit of the $g_n$ doesn't have a finite supremum.  $g_n$ **is** a Cauchy sequence whose limit is not in your function space.  You have bumped into the familiar fact that in finite dimensional vector spaces "complete" $\iff$ "Cauchy sequences have limits".  This is no longer (automatically) true in infinite dimensional spaces.  You have stated examples.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you have to be careful with $C[0,1]$ is that there are different notions of convergence.  For example, the sequence of functions given by $f_n(x)=x^n$ converges to zero pointwise, but definitely not uniformly.  $C[0,1]$ is complete under the max norm, i.e. given $f,g\in C[0,1]$  we have,

$$\|f-g\|_{\infty}=\max_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)| $$ which is the norm of uniform convergence (I'm using the word maximum now, but this notation eventually refers to taking the supremum later in your Carothers).  If I know $f_n\longrightarrow f$ under the max norm, this is the same thing as saying $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$. There are certain theorems which allow you to throw out "small sets" of points to make pointwise convergence become uniform, but that's for a measure theory discussion.

For the functions given in (b), each one of the $g_n$ is an element in $C[0,1]$, but the pointwise limit is not.  Once again, we are able to pop out of the space of continuous functions by only looking at pointwise convergence instead of uniform convergence.  I hope that helps.

Comment: So both function sequence(b) and function sequence(c) are not Cauchy sequence, right?